# Dagger 2 - how to create/provide a EagerSingleton

Tags: singleton, eager-loading, dagger-2

I am having trouble with the Dagger 2 dependency injection framework.  I would like to create an *EagerSingleton*. I assume that dagger 2 creates lazy loaded singletons when I use the `@Singleton` annotation. How do I create *EagerSingleton* using the Dagger 2 framework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this:

as per the [docs](http://square.github.io/dagger/) dagger does not support eagerSingletons directly so:

*Work around this by creating an EagerSingletons class that declares static fields for each eager singleton.
Method injection.*

So i created a EagerSingletons class in any module i want to use a eager singleton. In that eagerSingletons class i would declare any singleton i want to use. Thats it, dagger then makes the singletons eager.

UPDATE: The reason i used dagger 1 as an example, is this is how its done in dagger 2.  there really is no mechanism for eagerSingletons. you have to make it using a static field.  Let me give you an example of how you might create a eagerSingleton:

```
In every module you need a eager singleton you could have this:
    //assume this file is called myModule.java



static EagerObjects eagerObjects;

    public static void initEagerObjects() {
        if (eagerObjects == null) {
            eagerObjects = new EagerObjects();
        }
    }
//so far so good, only one object will be created, lets inject what we need immediately
    public static class EagerObjects {

        public EagerObjects() {
          //inject right away,you'll have to figure out a way to pass the graph in. by constructor param should be fine
            getGraph().inject(this);
        }

        //make this injection static
        @Inject
        static CoffeePot coffeePot;
    }
}
```

Now to find a way to call this right away on application launch....

Back in your dagger component or in the application class you extend you can have a static method to call each one of these per module:

```
  static void injectAllEagerObjects() {
            myModule.initEagerObjects();
            someOtherModule.initEagerObjects();
            //...all of them can be here since there static
```

}

now we are almost done, just have to call it at application launch. 
So right after you create your graph from application you have to call injectAllEagerObjects() (and probably pass in your graph instance there if you want).  This will initialize the eager singletons right way and only once.

all this being said, i wish dagger just had a annotation you could use like this:
@singleton(eager=true) but static fields, this is what they recommend for now.

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example of how you do this please, it would make this answer a lot more useful.

Comment: this does not work in dagger 2, the link you provided is for dagger 1.

Comment: i updated my answer with details. Please upvote if helpful as i spent time to create it and more votes helps others use this technique which saves developers time.

Comment: Do you know why they recommend static fields?  I'm using an `EagerSingletons` class with non-static fields.  I inject an instance of it and throw it away.  This seems to work fine.

Answer (score 11):

I solved this by creating an `EagerModule` which had a single provide method which returned `Void`.  Everything I wanted created eagerly I specified as parameters to that method.  Then I added a `Void init()` method to the Component which I call immediately after creating the Component.

```
@Module
public class EagerModule {

    @Provides
    @Nullable
    Void provideEager(...) {
        // this eagerly builds any parameters specified and returns nothing
        return null;
    }
}

@Component(modules = {EagerModule.class})
public interface TestComponent {

    @Nullable
    Void init();
}
```

This obviously doesn't give you access to the eagerly created singletons, but for my usage I didn't need access, I just wanted them created.

Comment: @Nullable wasn't on my classpath, added `com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305` to fix this

Answer (score 3):

It can be solved by using dagger multibindings. First, you need to create the interface:

```
public interface EagerInit {    
    void eagerInit();
}
```

In the `EagerModule` you bind `EagerInit` implementations to set, so you can access it in the `EagerComponent`:

```
@Module
public abstract class EagerModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoSet
    abstract EagerInit eagerInitImpl1(EagerInitImpl1 eagerInitImpl1);

    @Binds
    @IntoSet
    abstract EagerInit eagerInitImpl2(EagerInitImpl2 eagerInitImpl2);

}

@Component(modules = {EagerModule.class})
public interface EagerComponent {

    Set<EagerInit> getEagerInits();

}
```

After creating the `EagerComponent` you simply call:

```
component.getEagerInits().forEach(EagerInit::eagerInit);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a copy-pastable example that I came up with for Dagger2, I don't think there is a way to avoid (redundantly) declaring in the component which modules have eager objects.

It would be nice if someone could provide a less boilerplate-y example.

#### Main.java

```
import dagger.Component;
import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestComponent component = DaggerTestComponent.create();
        System.out.println("Created component.");

        component.createEagerSingletons();
    }
}

@Component(modules = {TestModule1.class, TestModule2.class})
@Singleton
abstract class TestComponent {

    abstract EagerSingletons createEagerSingletons();

    static class EagerSingletons {
        @Inject EagerSingletons() { System.out.println("Building all eager objects.."); }

        @Inject TestModule1.EagerSingletons m1;
        @Inject TestModule2.EagerSingletons m2;
    }

}

@Module
class TestModule1 {
    static class Thing1 { @Inject Thing1(){}}
    static class Thing2 { @Inject Thing2(){}}

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Thing1 first() { return new Thing1(); }
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Thing2 secon() { return new Thing2(); }

    static class EagerSingletons {
        @Inject Thing1 a;
        @Inject Thing2 b;

        @Inject EagerSingletons() { System.out.println("[1] Eagerly built objects!"); }
    }

}

@Module
class TestModule2 {
    static class EagerSingletons {
        @Inject EagerSingletons() { System.out.println("[2] Eagerly built objects!"); }
    }
}
```

The main method will print:

```
Created component.
Building all eager objects..
[1] Eagerly built objects!
[2] Eagerly built objects!
```